# How does a cancelled Delaware Domestic LLC affect the company's California Foreign LLC?

Tags: business, corporate-law

A Delaware Domestic LLC is cancelled status.   The LLC has a California Foreign LLC.

Is the Californian Foreign LLC legally able to continue in business, if the Domestic LLC is in cancelled status?

Answer (score 2):

The 'California foreign LLC' is not a separate entity. There is one entity, the Delaware LLC, which happens to be registered with the Californian authorities as a foreign (out-of-state) LLC doing business in California.

If the Delaware LLC is dissolved then it doesn't exist. Therefore it can't do anything anywhere. Pretending to carry on business in the name of a non-existent company would be fraudulent.

Comment: Or maybe the Delaware LLC is related to a California LLC that is registered in Delaware as a foreign company doing business in Delaware.